# vuejs mobile router-link prevented by v-on:mouseover

Tags: javascript, vue.js

have this `for` list:

```
<li
  class="projects-item"
  v-for="project in filteredProjects"
  :key="project.id"
  v-on:mouseover="displayHoverInfo($event, project)"
  v-on:mouseleave="hover = false"
  >
  <router-link v-bind:to="'/project/' + project.slug">
```

and js:

```
displayHoverInfo(event, project) {
  this.hover = true;
  this.hoveredProject = project;
  console.log(event);
}
```

on desktop works all fine, on mobile (on tap) only the v-on:mouseover/v-on:mouseleave events are being triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stole the answer here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-disable-mouseover-on-mobile/37335

You can disable the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` on mobile. Going further you can detect if it's actually a mobile/tablet using the user agent.

```
<li
  class="projects-item"
  v-for="project in filteredProjects"
  :key="project.id"
  v-on:mouseover="isMobile ? null : displayHoverInfo($event, project)"
  v-on:mouseleave="isMobile ? null : hover = false"
  >
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    isMobile: false,
    hover: false
  },

  methods: {
    mq() {
        this.isMobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 400px)').matches;
    },
    displayHoverInfo($event, project) {
        // your method
    }
  },

  created () {
    // get initial val
    this.mq()
    // listen to resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.mq)
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.mq)
  }
})
```

Comment: ok, it doesn't work because: `isMobile` is being init on false and there is no check on load, just added event listener for resize. so a check on load should be done too. cool! thanks for the answer and can you please add `this.mq()` on created?